# Are these figurines from any recognisable franchise?

Tags: character-identification, object-identification, toys

[image: seven plastic figures]

As a kid in the eighties, I used to play with these plastic space soldiers, lovingly painted by my grandfather.

I just rediscovered them and immediately wondered if they're from an actual franchise, or just sprang from some manufacturer's imagination.

They're the same size as "regular" toy soldiers, about 6 cm. in height. They are made in one part out of grey plastic, which is coming through in parts where the paint has chipped.

I could not find any identification mark anywhere on the figurines. They're from the early to mid eighties, but may have been bought earlier.

I assume my grandfather used his imagination and whatever colours he happened to have on hand, so the colours may not match with any franchise.

Comment: There's a centurion with a rebel trooper blaster and Killer Croc wearing a punk Black Manta helmet while wielding a shark-finned gun. I dig it.

Comment: You, my friend, had one heck of a grandfather. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis I absolutely did.

Comment: Awesome collection! Please never lose them.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

These are [Airfix Space Warriors](http://www.vintage-airfix.com/airfix/space/space-warriors-p-857.html).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so ... no franchise ?

Comment: @bolov: franchise licenses are expensive

Comment: Wow. Nice to learn he did paint these according to the scheme. Would you mind sharing (in your answer) how you managed to find these?

Comment: @SQB - Well, as soon as I read the question properly and realised that they were bare plastic, doing a search for [airfix space soldiers] was sufficient to find them

Comment: @Valorum ah. I just didn't think of Airfix. In hindsight, duh!